# How can I selectively clear redis cache?

Tags: spring, redis

I have a Spring Boot application that is caching some values such as <UserId, MyPojo.class>.

Example MyPojo fields:

- id
- code

If a change is made to MyPojo.code then I want to clear the cache for all users that have that MyPojo.id.

I've looked at `@CacheEvict` annotation with a condition, but that seems to be only for deciding whether to evict cache on some condition without checking what is present in the cache itself.

Another option would be to iterate through every cache entry and check the value and clear that key, but that seems expensive.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Switch key/value and your life will be easier ;)

When you make changes to the  object that is stored as value in the cache on key  you have two ways to clear only the relevant cached objects:

1. MyPojo has a reference to all UserId's that "has" this pojo (not likely). Then you would simply take that list of UserId's and for each call a method annotaded with @CacheEvict that takes UserId as parameter. This will indicate that UserId is the key to evict from the cache.
2. Get the Native Cache implementation with cache.getNativeCache() then loop through this cache's entries and check if <cached MyPojo's id> == <modified MyPojo's id>. If so evict it from cache. This would depend on your cache implementation so look up how to do this for Redis.

If I were you I would switch to using MyPojo.id as key, and store some List as the cached value. Then if you make changes to the MyPojo you can simply evict that id from the cache.